# How to draw tiled image with QT

Tags: c++, image, qt

I'm writing interface with C++/Qt in QtCreator's designer. What element to chose to make as a rect with some background image?

And the second question: how to draw tiled image? I have and image with size (1×50) and I want to render it for the parent width. Any ideas?

---

```
mTopMenuBg = QPixmap("images/top_menu_bg.png");
mTopMenuBrush = QBrush(mTopMenuBg);
mTopMenuBrush.setStyle(Qt::TexturePattern);
mTopMenuBrush.setTexture(mTopMenuBg);

ui->graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(mTopMenuBrush);
```

> QBrush: Incorrect use of
>   TexturePattern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to show an image you can use [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html).  To make a background with the image tiled construct a [QBrush](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbrush.html) with the QImage.  Then, if you were using [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsscene.html) for example, you could set the bursh as the background brush.

Here is an example which fills the entire main window with the tiled image "document.png":

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow();

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(100, 100, 100, 100);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    mainWindow->setCentralWidget(view);

    QImage *image = new QImage("document.png");
    if(image->isNull()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load the image." <<std::endl;
    } else {
        QBrush *brush = new QBrush(*image);
        view->setBackgroundBrush(*brush);
    }

    mainWindow->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The resulting app:
[image: screen shot]

Alternatively, it seems that you could use [style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html) with any widget and change the [background-image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#background-image-prop) property on the widget.  This has more integration with QtDesigner as you can set the style sheet and image in [QtDesigner](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-stylesheet.html).

Comment: Sorry, can't understand how to fill the exact rect in my window with that brush. And where to draw? In `paintEvent`?

Comment: Do you just want to fill a window with a tiled image?  What kind of widget do you have that you want to put the image on?

Comment: @dusty-campbell Yeah, I just need to fill some rect in my main window with tiled texture. I don't care what helper-widget to use.

Comment: So if you create a QGraphicsView then set the backgroundBrush to a QBrush create with the QImage, I think you'll get what you want.